# dynamic default value in python

Tags: python-3.x, default-value

I have a case where I am trying to make a code similar to below print 2 instead of 1.

```
class foo():
    _default_val = 1
    @classmethod
    def print_num(cls, num=_default_val):
        print(num)

class foo2(foo):
    _default_val = 2

tester = foo2()
tester.print_num()
# 1
```

Of course I could set `num=None` and access `self._default_val` if it is still `None`, however I would like to know if there is a neater way of achieving this.

Note: I am also aware it would work if I copy paste the function but I consider this as bad practice since I would have to maintain all copies of that function for every change I make

Answer (score -1):

The standard way is indeed to set the default to `None` and check if it `is not None`.

This is so commonly used that other Python developpers will immediately understand what you intended, so you should not try to reinvent the wheel.

```
class Foo():
    _default_val = 1

    @classmethod
    def print_num(cls, num=None):
        num = num if num is not None else cls._default_val
        print(num)

class Foo2(Foo):
    _default_val = 2

tester = Foo2()
tester.print_num(0) # prints: 0
tester.print_num() # prints: 2
```